# Table doesn't exist with Django Chartit raw query

Tags: python, mysql, django, charts

I'm getting a problem with `Django Chartit` from my views.py file because he doesn't find my table. However this table exists in my `MySQL Database`.

I'm using this module in order to display some graphics in my Django website and it's the first time I'm using it.

I have a table which is named `Person` in my `Identity` application like this :

```
class Person(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=12,choices=TITLE_CHOICES, verbose_name='Civilité')
    young_girl_lastname = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='Nom de jeune fille', blank=True)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='Nom de famille')
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='Prénom(s)')
    sex = models.CharField(max_length=8, choices=SEX_CHOICES, verbose_name='Sexe')
    birthday = models.DateField(verbose_name='Date de naissance')
    birthcity = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='Ville de naissance')
    birthcountry = CountryField(blank_label='Sélectionner un pays', verbose_name='Pays de naissance')
    .....
```

In my MySQL Database, I have this :

```
mysql> show tables ;
+-------------------------------------+
| Tables_in_DatasystemsEC             |
+-------------------------------------+
| BirthCertificate_birthcertificate   |
| Configurations_theme                |
| Identity_monthlyweatherbycity       |
| Identity_person                     |
| Mairie_mairie                       |
| Recensement_attestation_recensement |
| auth_group                          |
| auth_group_permissions              |
| auth_permission                     |
| auth_user                           |
| auth_user_groups                    |
| auth_user_user_permissions          |
| django_admin_log                    |
| django_content_type                 |
| django_migrations                   |
| django_session                      |
| log_userprofile                     |
+-------------------------------------+
```

You have `Identity_person` as table.

In my view, I defined a new function in order to display some statistics graphics :

```
def Chartview(request) :

    #Step 1: Create a DataPool with the data we want to retrieve.
    ds = \
        DataPool(
           series=
            [{'options': {
               'source': Person.objects.raw(
                   "SELECT birthcountry, COUNT(birthcountry) as nombre FROM Person GROUP BY birthcountry")
            },
              'terms': [
                'birthcountry',
                'nombre']}
             ])

    #Step 2: Create the Chart object
    cht = Chart(
            datasource = ds,
            series_options =
              [{'options':{
                  'type': 'column',
                  'stacking': False},
                'terms':{
                  'birthcountry': [
                    'nombre']
                  }}],
            chart_options =
              {'title': {
                   'text': 'Nombre de naissances par pays'},
                'xAxis': {
                    'title': {
                       'text': 'Pays de naissance'}}})

    return render(request, 'statistics.html',{'birthcountrychart': cht})
```

But I get this error :

```
(1146, "Table 'DatasystemsEC.Person' doesn't exist")
```

I don't understand by what I have to replace : `Person.objects.raw`.
I tried `Identity_person.objects.raw` but it doesn't work.

Thank you by advance

**EDIT :**

I found another way to make my query with Django Aggregation thanks to @e4c5 and it works pretty well :

```
Person.objects.values('birthcountry').annotate(nombre = Count('birthcountry'))}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should write your SQL as:

```
'source': Person.objects.raw(
               "SELECT birthcountry, COUNT(birthcountry) as nombre FROM Identity_person GROUP BY birthcountry")
        },
```

Comment: Thank you ! You solved my problem even if I get another error : `Raw query must include the primary key`

Answer (score 1):

Mysql table names are case sensitive on most installations. The standard django table nomenclature is `appname_tablename` in all lower case so your should ideally have the following in your model:

```
class Meta:
    db_table = 'Identity_person'
```

Then your raw query also should have the proper table name

```
SELECT birthcountry, COUNT(birthcountry) as nombre FROM Identity_person GROUP BY birthcountry
```

I would however argue that you should use a django aggregation instead of a raw query here.

Comment: Thank you :) Why I should use Django aggregation ? Not easy to use `count`, `group by` sql functions with Django :/

Comment: Yes, this is one of django's biggest weaknesses.